# sql pivot table using actual weekdays and sum aggregation

Tags: sql, date, sum, pivot-table

I'm trying to get a pivot table using sum aggregation and creating a column for each weekday, this is what I have:

```
USER  ||  REPORTED TIME ||  REPORTING DAY

RAFA  ||       3        ||     05/05/12
RAFA  ||       3        ||     05/05/12
RAFA  ||       3        ||     05/05/12
RAFA  ||       6        ||     06/05/12
RAFA  ||       3        ||     06/05/12
JHON  ||       9        ||     07/05/12
JHON  ||       6        ||     08/05/12
JHON  ||       3        ||     08/05/12

the result im expenting is this:

USER || THIS_WEEK_MONDAY_HOURS || THIS_WEEK_THUESDAY_HOURS || THIS_WEEK_WEDNESDAY_HOURS

RAFA ||            9           ||             9            ||              0         
JHON ||            0           ||             0            ||              9
```

I really don't have any idea how to make it, i was trying but i don't understand how to create the actual week day and deposit the sum aggregation hours in there.

Comment: Show us your query with just dates.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe somebody gives you a pivot solution but you can get it using SUM and CASE

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, [REPORTTING DAY]) = 0 THEN [REPORTED TIME] ELSE 0) as SUNDAY,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, [REPORTTING DAY]) = 1 THEN [REPORTED TIME] ELSE 0) as MONDAY,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, [REPORTTING DAY]) = 2 THEN [REPORTED TIME] ELSE 0) as TUESDAY,
    ....
    ....
FROM
    YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY USER
```

keep in mind that depending on your regional settings, Day=0 can be Monday or Sunday.